# Telegram bot GetUpdate returns {"ok":true,"result":[]}

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Good afternoon!

My telegram bot is written in Python and is very simple. It includes thousands of lines of functions of the same type (example below) and ends with a line bot.infinity_polling(True)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def com_start(m):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Русский']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['English']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['German']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Turkish']])

    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Привет!',
                           reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, starter)


def starter(m):

    if m.text == 'Русский':
        second(m)

    elif m.text == 'English':
       secondeng(m)

    elif m.text == 'German':
       secondgerm(m)

    elif m.text == 'Turkish':
        secondtur(m)

    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Используйте кнопки меню для общения с ботом OTON ⤵️')
        com_start(m)
```

My bot works with gitlab, after each change in the code I commit, push it and Run Pipeline via CI/CD.

The problem is that the GetUpdates method (https://api.telegram.org/bot.../getUpdates) while the bot is **running** gives {"ok":true,"result":[]} and nothing more. But when I **stop** the bot and refresh the page - it gives me all that I need:

{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":57670007,
"message":{"message_id":10586,"from":{"id":435418164,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Nika","last_name":"Fenina","username":"yanikailinet","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":435418164,"first_name":"Nika","last_name":"Fenina","username":"yanikailinet","type":"private"},"date":1590065990,"text":"hello"}}

Can I solve this problem somehow? I need to get the information I need while the bot is running.

PS: no webhooks connected

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make simultaneous getUpdates requests. It shows this error.

```
Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

You can save the information of ["result"] inside the code only in some file.